# Assigning variables in for loop in bash

Tags: bash, for-loop

The following bash script works fine to print numbers from 1 to 10:

```
for i in {1..10}
do
  echo "$i"
done
```

But if I want to make the upper limit a variable, then this script does not works.

```
i=10
for j in {1..$i}
do
  echo "$j"
done
```

Can anyone suggest please how to make the second script work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Brace expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion) happens before any other expansion.

You can say:

```
for j in $(seq 1 $i); do echo "$j"; done
```

Quoting from the link above:

> Brace expansion is performed before any other expansions, and any
>   characters special to other expansions are preserved in the result. It
>   is strictly textual. Bash does not apply any syntactic interpretation
>   to the context of the expansion or the text between the braces. To
>   avoid conflicts with parameter expansion, the string `‘${’` is not
>   considered eligible for brace expansion.

Comment: Just wondering about history of `seq` command since I could never use it on my Mac.

Comment: @anubhava I'm not sure which OSX version you're using, but I've found it to exist on any variant that I've used, 10.8.x or 10.5.x  or whatever ...

Comment: @anubhava Maybe you did `sudo rm -f $(which seq)` and have forgotten doing so!

Comment: lol :) I must be really insane to remove a system binary, Why would anyone do that?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use variables in `{..}` directive of Bash. Use BASH arithmetic operator `((...))` like this:

```
i=10
for ((j=1; j<=i; j++)); do
    echo "$j"
done
```

Comment: a space would be needed here between for and bracket? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @prabhat: As you can space is already there after `for` but for me it worked with or without space.